# How to transform ratio input features in deep learning

Tags: neural-networks, data-transformation, feature-engineering

I am a recommender system study which predict how likely a user browsing a product A will but another product B. One of the features is the price ratio of A and B, i.e., PriceB/PriceA. The assumption is that if the price difference of A and B is huge, probably A and B are not relevant or replaceable. I'd like to equally penalize too much pricer and too much cheaper products.

However, the range of PriceB/PriceA is [0, +inf) and the value can be very large. So I change the feature to log(PriceB/PriceA).

If PriceA=$60, PriceB=$30, then log(PriceB/PriceA)=-0.69.

If PriceA=$60, PriceB=$60, then log(PriceB/PriceA)=0.

If PriceA=$60, PriceB=$90, then log(PriceB/PriceA)=0.4.

It seems that this ratio feature penalizes more when PriceB < PriceA. Is there better way to model this feature? Any way to get even (non-linear) larger penalty on both side, such as y=x^3?